# Are there any alternatives to using TextGeometry for VR applications built with Three.JS that offer better performance?

Tags: text, three.js, virtual-reality

I just implemented a scoring system for a VR game that I'm working on. But performance is suffering and I think that it's because of how I'm rendering the score. Performance issues started right after I implemented scoring.

I'm creating a new THREE.Mesh with a new THREE.TextGeometry, and then adding it to the scene each time that the score changes. As far as I understand, the string that is being rendered in a TextGeometry object cannot be changed dynamically, so a whole new object needs to be created.

The following happens every time the score changes:

```
    this.scene.remove( this.text );
    this.material = this.assetStore.mainEmissiveMaterial;
    this.geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( String(this.score), {
        font: this.assetStore.mainFont,
        size: 6,
        height: 0,
    } );
    this.geometry.translate(-10, 25, -40);
    this.text = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
    this.scene.add( this.text );
```

**My question**: Is there an alternative way of showing text, that doesn't affect performance as much?

Comment: @Marquizzo Do you want to copy and paste your comment as the answer so that I can select it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with geometries, you shouldn't create and destroy them each time you need to update. This kills your performance. Instead, create all 10 digits `0123456789`, save them as your templates, and then re-use them. Show and hide them and duplicate them as necessary, but don't re-build thousands of vertices and faces each time the text changes.