# Update textGeometry text dynamically

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi i wanted do make a 3d clock in ThreeJS that displays current time, but i found no way to update the text i tried multiple codes from othre platforms but they were too complicated to use or just didnt work, is there any simple way to update text in real time?
heres the code

```
fontLoader.load('./fonts/Digital-7_Regular.json', function (font) {
    const time = new Date()
    let hour = time.getHours()
    let minute = time.getMinutes()
    let second = time.getSeconds()


    const textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(`${hour}:${minute}:${second}`, {
        font: font,
        size: 1,
        height: 1
    })

    const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x00ff00
        })
    ])

    scene.add(textMesh)
    textMesh.scale.set(.3, .3, .3)
    textMesh.position.x = -0.45
    textMesh.position.y = -0.75
    textMesh.position.z = 0.06

    function updateTime(){
        hour = time.getHours()
        minute = time.getMinutes()

        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime)
    }
    
    updateTime()
})
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. To my knowledge text geometry is meant to be created once and then be static. But if it's just a clock, why not create one geometry for each digit from 0 to 9, as well as your delimiter character, and display them side by side while hiding/showing the appropriate ones each second?

Comment: Might be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66461937/are-there-any-alternatives-to-using-textgeometry-for-vr-applications-built-with